# AWS Cloudformation RDS EnablePerformanceInsights is not working

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I want to create RDS instance trough Clouformation. Below the excerpt from the cloudformation file.

```
  MasterDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBName
      BackupRetentionPeriod: !Ref DBBackupRetentionPeriod
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      DBInstanceClass: "db.t3.medium"
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      Engine: MySQL
      AvailabilityZone: !Ref DBAvailabilityZone
      EngineVersion: "5.7.30"
      MasterUsername: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/DB/USER:1}}"
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm-secure:/DB/PASSWORD:1}}"
      MultiAZ: !Ref MultiAZ
      EnablePerformanceInsights: 'true'
      DeletionProtection: 'true'
      DBParameterGroupName: !Ref RDSDBParameterGroup
```

The RDS is created without a problem, but I've noticed that Performance Insights and Deletion protection is not enabled on the new instance.

Could you advise why these options don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **verified** your template in my sandbox account in `us-east-1`, and it the insights and deletion protection are **enabled** as expected.

The template I used was as follows (mostly just commented out the references not shown in your question):

```
Resources:
  MasterDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      #DBName: !Ref DBName
      #DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBName
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 0
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBInstanceClass: "db.t3.medium"
      #DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      Engine: MySQL
      #AvailabilityZone: !Ref DBAvailabilityZone
      EngineVersion: "5.7.30"
      MasterUsername: root
      MasterUserPassword: fsdf45454
      MultiAZ: false
      EnablePerformanceInsights: 'true'
      DeletionProtection: 'true'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did it in the us-west-2 region. And see these values:

Performance Insights enabled
No

Deletion protection
Disabled

It will probably be better to ask the support about that.